# How to use libraries which have been required by RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have tried to import [MQTT](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt) using [REQUIREJS](https://requirejs.org/) but I am getting an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: mqtt is not defined

The code I am trying to run is in an HTML file:

**HTML**

```
    <script>
    require(["https://unpkg.com/mqtt@3.0.0/dist/mqtt.min.js"], function (mqtt) {
        console.log("Libraries loaded");
    })
</script>
<script src="../text-to-speech/sub_mqtt.js"></script>
```

**sub_mqtt**

```
    //MQTT Connection
function mqtt_connect() {
    //var mqtt = require('mqtt'); // Should I use it?
    var client = mqtt.connect({ host: 'test', port: port })
    var topic = 'mytopic'

    client.on('message', (topic, message) => {
    });


    client.on('connect', () => {
        client.subscribe(topic);
        console.log("Connected!")
    });
};

mqtt_connect();
```

I know that if I copy this code into the first `script` call back, I would solve the error, but I would like to do it in a different file to avoid overcrowding the HTML.

Comment: Put the require call to the sub_mqtt file too. It doesn't have to be in the HTML.

Comment: Also, if you want to keep the require call in the HTML, all you need to move to the callback is `mqtt_connect()`. The function itself can be in a different file, especially if you move the script that contains the function so that it loads before requiring the library.

Comment: How can I add the call back to my js file

Comment: I don't understand the question. What callback?

Comment: Sorry I misread your answer. You were right. It works. Thanks buddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RequireJS is async module loader, so your method of loading is wrong because you have no guarantee that mqtt will be loaded before your script.

To make sure that your code will be executed after mqtt load, you have to pass it as callback to RequireJS. First, amend your HTML code to:

```html
<script src="../text-to-speech/sub_mqtt.js"></script>
```

Then edit your `sub_mqtt` script and make sure that your code is a callback to RequireJS:

```js
require(['https://unpkg.com/mqtt@3.0.0/dist/mqtt.min.js'], function (mqtt) {
    var client = mqtt.connect({ host: 'test', port: port })
    var topic = 'mytopic'

    client.on('message', (topic, message) => {
    });


    client.on('connect', () => {
        client.subscribe(topic);
        console.log("Connected!")
    });
});
```